# Using PushSharp with multiple apple channels

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am new to PushSharp and trying to understand how to use it.

I have a situation where I have different versions of an apple app. E.g.: MyApp, MyAppHD, MyAppPremium, MyAppPremiumHD.
I have differernt bundle identifiers for these and 4 different push certificates.

When I am collecting the device pushid's I know which one belongs to which bundle identifier.

My question is, if I use this with PushSharp, do I create 4 different PushService instances? or Do I add 4 Apple channels to one PushService?

If I am able to use 4 channels, how do I specify which channel a particular device belongs to?

If I create multiple instances, I wanted to know if there is a major performance hit doing that or it is irrelevant at this point?

Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use 4 PushBroker (the new PushService in the v2).

There is no problem to have many PushBroker, each one is really light.

And it's more easy to control each application if one application is manage by one service.